# How to control a trackbar by textbox (C#)

Tags: c#, textbox, trackbar

I'm trying to make my trackbar moving (changing value) each time the user is changing a text in a textbox. I've found a similar topic here, but the code below doesn't make a change:

```
private void RedTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    RedBar.Value = int.Parse(RedTextBox.Text);
}
```

Where `RedTexBox` is my textbox, `RedBar` is a trackBar

Comment: What are the value of the rest of the relevant properties for the TrackBar, like `Minimum` and `Maximum`?

Comment: If you change the code to use an internal `int`, and you increment that `int` on every pass through, and set the value with that `int` does the `TrackBar` respond? In other words, I want to get rid of the `TextBox` for a minute and eliminate it from the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you entering text that can be parsed into numbers? Because that is what your code assumes.

If you just want the value to change (irrespectively of what the text input is), I'd do something like:

```
private void RedTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
     RedBar.Value += 1; 
     if (RedBar.Value == RedBar.Maximum){ RedBar.Value = RedBar.Minimum; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK i got it!:)
it just needed to be :

(...)  `private void RedTextBox_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)`    (...)

I don't know what diffrence makes the "_1", but it works now
Thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

The "_1" means you have rebuilt the method with a new control on your form and have used the same name. If you are trying to bring a `float` type to `int` I have used two conversions to make the change with good results.

```
    private void oGTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var oGValue = double.Parse(oGTextBox.Text) * 1000;
    trackBar1.Value = int.Parse(oGValue.ToString());
}
```

This was used for specific gravity and displaying the decimal place as such... 1.050.
 But as I have mentioned before. The rebuilding of controls on form while using the same name was your underlying cause of errors.